# How to run Glade and Devhelp after installing with MSYS2

Tags: c++, gtk, glade, msys2

I was following the steps on the official GTK+ website. (https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) 
However, after finishing those steps, how do I run them?

Comment: Running what actually? The [_"halp me plz pagez"_](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/08/01/how-to-build-your-gtk-application-on-windows/)?

Comment: How to run Glade and Devhelp.

Comment: @TheDude: your link is about how to package GTK+ applications for MSYS2 and has no relation with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2020-02-28 EDIT:**

MSYS2 no longer provides the Devhelp package.

See https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5805

**Original version:**

I wrote that page. Found that so obvious that I didn't mention it but maybe that's just because I'm too used to the UNIX way of doing things. To run a tool in command line, you just type its name and press enter. So just type `devhelp` or `glade`.

You can also use autocompletion and just press the beginning of a word like `gla`, press the `Tab` key, and the available choice will appear.

You may append the `&` sign at the end of the command to run it in the background so you can still use your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for answering